# 'Truncated incorrect Value' error while inserting text as date using str_to_date()

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, str-to-date

I am looking for a query resolution for one of insert scenarios in MySQL.

Below is the scenario:

```
create table test (test_date date);
insert  into test values (str_to_date('16/04/1991','%d/%m/%y'))
```

MySQL is not allowing me to insert this record and displays an error "Truncated incorrect value"
I tried using `IGNORE`:

```
insert ignore into test values (str_to_date('16/04/1991','%d/%m/%y'))
```

but it captured year as 2019.

Please help.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
insert  into test values (str_to_date('16/04/1991','%d/%m/%Y'))
```

It should be %Y for year

Please refer this [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a warning, not an error, it happens because MySQL is running in Strict Mode. In Strict Mode, warnings become errors when trying to INSERT/UPDATE. To disable strict mode, you can put `SET sql_mode = '';` in the beginning of your query.